# Parse JSON hash and output contents as plaintext 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am new to Rails and stuck on a silly doubt. I have a JSON object @data as:

```
@data = '{"A":"aa", "B":"bb","C":"cc"}'
```

i want this to be displayed as:

> A is aa
>   B is bb
>   C is cc

How can i achieve this using my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original question, `{"A"="aa", "B"="bb","C"="cc"}` is not valid JSON.  So either you're not getting a valid JSON object or what you actually have is a Ruby hash like Thomas pointed out.

Assuming you actually have a valid JSON string:

```
@data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode('{"A":"aa","B":"bb","C":"cc"}')
string_version = @data.map{|k,v| "#{k} is #{v}"}.join(' and ')
puts string_version
```

Assuming you actually have a Ruby hash:

```
@data = Hash.new
@data = {"A"=>"aa", "B"=>"bb", "C"=>"cc"}
string_version = @data.map{|k,v| "#{k} is #{v}"}.join(' and ')
puts string_version
```